# Could 'heresy' be an accusation at those who follow the philosophy of Heraclitus?

Tags: etymology, philosophy

The wisdom of the world Tertullian (c160-240)pp-5&6 in Documents of the Christian Church 2nd edition by Henry Betterson:....any assertion about the God of fire,then Heraclitus comes in. Heretics and philosophers handle the same subject matter; both treat of the same topics-Whence came evil...whence came God?

Comment: We say "accusation *against*".  You omit any identification of the people who would be making such an accusation.  Are you asking if *Tertullian* is calling (or can rightfully call) followers of Heraclitus heretics?

Comment: _Heresy_ can be used as an accusation against absolutely anyone, as long as the person making the accusation perceives it as something you can accuse someone of. The same goes for just about anything else. What does that have to do with Heraclitus?

Comment: No 'heresy' does not apply to him. 'heraclitean' would be the corresponding adjective. There's no school associated with him. He is usually labeled simply a 'pre-Socratic'.

Comment: I have no idea what this question is about, although it may simply be asking whether followers of Heraclitus are generically called "heretics" in the same way as Christians follow Christ. (Is that what it's asking?) There is a clue in the spellings, though.

Comment: dear Tim, yes I wonder if heresy may be a reference to philosophy of Heraclitus,causing strife and unwanted transformation of belief, instead of a term for philosophy of choice.

Answer (score 3):

According to Etymonline **[heresy](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Heresy&searchmode=none)** does not originate from Heraclitus:

> - "an opinion of private men different from that of the catholick and orthodox church" [Johnson], c. 1200, **from Old French heresie (12c.), from Latin hæresis, "school of thought, philosophical sect," used by Christian writers for "unorthodox sect or doctrine,"** from Greek hairesis "a taking or choosing, a choice," **from haireisthai "take, seize," middle voice of hairein "to choose," of unknown origin, perhaps from PIE *ser- (5) "to seize"** (cognates: Hittite šaru "booty," Welsh herw "booty").
> - The Greek word was used in the New Testament in reference to the Sadducees, Pharisees, and even the Christians, as sects of Judaism, but in English bibles it usually is translated sect. Meaning "religious belief opposed to the orthodox doctrines of the Church" evolved in Late Latin. Transferred (non-religious) use from late 14c.

Comment: Faith is resolute,religion and heresy are fluid. Heraclitus philosophised the fluidity of natural/corporal experience and the strife that shaped the inconsistent form. Heresy is the partner in strife of religion.

Comment: @Analogue girl-        This is a site about English language usage. Heresy does not derive from Heraclitus. For issues about faith you should ask the Religions site.

Comment: thanks Josh, could hairein come from goddess Hera who as a god chose to be a domestic goddess to protect the haven of the hearth and Zeus her sibling husband concentrated on providing and protecting outside the home.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Heraclitus of Ephesus lived c. 535 – c. 475 BCE. I assume that he may have had followers before Christianity, thus if this is an accusation **with regard to Roman Catholic dogma**, it would not work for those before the period of Christ.

There's this meaning:

> **her·e·sy** noun
>
> plural -es 1
>
> b :  a deliberate and obstinate denial of a revealed truth by a
>   baptized member of the **Roman Catholic Church**
>
> Merriam-Webster Unabridged Dictionary

Comment: Im an Anglican,born innocent and remain thus until proven guilty.